# else statement still runs even when else if condtions pass

Tags: java, database, sqlite, if-statement

I'm having issues getting my if else statement to work correctly, here I have a login in form that uses values from a database. The statement for the Employee role works fine but even if the else if statement passes the else statement still runs.

If it helps the dialog box appears twice if the Customer statement passes and three time if the else runs by itself. I apologize if my code format is off I'm new at posting code here.

```
 private void jBtnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // action performed when the login button is pressed
    // variables that will contain the row entries to the login data base (user name)
    String userNameDb = "";            
    roleDb = rs.getString("role");
    //database connection code
    try
    {      
   Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("//database directory");       
   st=con.createStatement();
   //selects entries from the userName password and role row from the user table
   rs=st.executeQuery("Select userName, role From tblUser ;");        

   //loops through the table entires
    while(rs.next())
    {    
        //assigns database entry to variables        
        userNameDb = rs.getString("userName");
        roleDb = rs.getString("role");

    if (jTxtUserName.getText().equals(userNameDb) && roleDb.equals("Customer"))             
    {
        //switch forms
        break;
    }
    //if the users input and role match the data base for an customer send them to the selection form
    else if (jTxtUserName.getText().equals(userNameDb) && roleDb.equals("Customer")) 
    {
       //switch forms           
       break;
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed");

    }
        }
    }
        catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("" + ex); 
    }          
  }
}
```

Comment: There is some code missing above the snippet, a `for` or `while` loop maybe?

Comment: A decent [mcve] would be worth its weight in gold here

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but *please* fix that formatting. Let your IDE do it for you, but fix it. You're making it harder on us (and on yourself) than it has to be. Please (again) look at the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link provided above and try to post one.

Comment: Ah I see thanks for the hint NickL, so the issue wasn't isolated in the if-else statement, I'll re-post the entire code block, now based off that I've tested it again it does in fact run through each entry in the table until it finds a match. So the question now is how to loop though the table without triggering the else condition.

Comment: @trulbul: you can't. The answer is to put the test of ultimate pass / fail *outside* the while loop. Please see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your while loop is coded wrong as your "Login failed" JOptionPane else block shouldn't be within the while loop. Instead declare a boolean value before the loop, set it to false, check if the username/password are found within the that loop, and if so, set the boolean to true. Then *after* the loop check the boolean value, and if false, show the error message.

To see why, use a debugger to run through the code to see why it's behaving the way it's behaving. More importantly, learn the "rubber duck" debugging technique where you walk through your code mentally or on paper, telling the duck what each line of code should be doing.

To illustrate, your code is behaving something like the code below where a boolean array is mimicking your password username check. Of course, you'd be using a while loop, not a for loop, but this was used here to make the example simpler:

```
private someActionPerformedMethod() {
    // boolean representing when the username/password test is OK
    boolean[] loopItems = { false, false, false, true, false };
    for (boolean loopItem : loopItems) {
        if (loopItem) {
            break;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Assume that the password/username only matches on the 4th try (forth item is `true`), then for each failed check, the JOptionPane will show a failed login. What you want instead is something like:

```
private someActionPerformedMethod() {
    // boolean representing when the username/password test is OK
    boolean[] loopItems = { false, false, false, true, false };
    boolean userFound = false;

    // you'll of course be using a while loop here
    for (boolean loopItem : loopItems) {
        if (loopItem) {
            userFound = true;
            // do something with user data
            break;              
        }
    }
    if (!userFound) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed");
    }
}
```